# In a loop is possible to get the value of start and end values of the control variable?

Tags: c#, for-loop

The title says it all, but I will add a code example to make it more clear.

```
Random r = new Random(); 
for (int i = r.Next(0, 5); i < r.Next(6, 20); i++)
{
    int start = ?
    int end = ?
}
```

Comment: you shouln't do `i < r.Next(6, 20)` it will cause your programm to get a new value every time your loop is checking if it sould continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move declaration of start and end outside the loop:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
int start = r.Next(0, 5);
int end = r.Next(6, 20);
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
    // Your code goes here.

    // If you want to generate a new end criteria for each iteration in a similar way 
    // as your example, you need to add this to the end of the loop:
    end = r.Next(6, 20); 
}
```

Running `i < r.Next(6, 20)` in the for loop criteria block would generate a new number for each iteration, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: In the OP's example, the condition until the loop keeps going is changing each time.

Comment: Indeed. Probably not what OP intended, though.

Comment: You could solve the issue by doing `end = r.Next(6,20)` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @npinti: Can you develop? You mean like this? for (int i = r.Next(0, 5), end = r.Next(6, 20); i < end; i++ )

Comment: It should be just as what this answer has provided.